# Manage multiple Websocket client connection with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, websocket

I'm implementing a websocket client in node and my webhook's trying to handle multiple connections from a chatbot service. For example: a new user income, a websocket connection is established on an external chatbot service. The websocket URL is obtained through XMLHttpRequest in my code. And then I use this url to connect to the chatbot service using the ws object (`new WebSocket('wssUrlObtainedThroughAjaxRequest','default-protocol')`). So each user have a WebSocket. The question is that my code runs sequentially. So if two people sends message to my webhook node, things don't works properly because parallelism. Well, I'll post example code here to make it better to understand.

```
const express = require('express');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8002;
let WebSocket = require('ws');
let CONNECTIONS = new Map();
...
...
...
const app = express()
    .use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
    .use(bodyparser.json());

app.post('/', (req, res) => { 
...
...
...
    } else if (req.body.type === 'MESSAGE') {

    let DM = req.body.space.name;
    let msg = req.body.message.text;

    ws = (CONNECTIONS.get(DM)!=null) ? CONNECTIONS.get(DM) : null;

    if(ws==null || ws.readyState==3){
      controlws.gerarURLWS();
      ws = new WebSocket(controlws.urlws, 'talk-protocol');
      CONNECTIONS.set(DM,ws);
    }

    // Executes on websocket openning
    ws.onopen = function (event) {
      console.log('Canal aberto;');
      keepAliveWS();
      ws.send(JSON.stringify(msgKoreAi(msg))); 
    }

    if(ws.readyState==1)
      ws.send(JSON.stringify(msgKoreAi(msg))); 

    ws.onmessage = async function (event) {
      let resp = JSON.parse(event.data);

      if (resp.type == "bot_response") {
        text = resp.message[0].component.payload.text;

        if(text==null){ // tem quick reply
          //mount card hangouts response 
          let qreplies = resp.message[0].component.payload.payload.quick_replies; 
          card = '{"sections": [{"widgets": [{"buttons": [';
          for(let i=0; i<qreplies.length; i++){
            if(i!=qreplies.length-1)
              card+='{"textButton": {"text": "'+qreplies[i].payload+'","onClick": {"action": {"actionMethodName": "'+qreplies[i].payload+'"}}}},';
            else
              card+='{"textButton": {"text": "'+qreplies[i].payload+'","onClick": {"action": {"actionMethodName": "'+qreplies[i].payload+'"}}}}';
          }      
          card+=']}]}],"name": "respostas"}';
          card = JSON.parse(card);

          text = resp.message[0].component.payload.payload.text; 
          {
            await assyncMessage(DM, text);
            await assyncMessage(DM, card);
          }
          return;
        }

        //Send assync messages if synchronous was already sent
        if(res.headersSent){
          {
            return await assyncMessage(DM, text);
          }
        }
        else
          return res.json({text});
      }
    }
    return;
  }
...
...
...
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running in port - ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: Hello, any work around for this. I am in same situation.